# QVBoxLayout text being clipped vertically as parent is resized

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a QVBoxLayout that seems to be squishing it's content when the container is resized horizontally. This is what it looks like when the window is at it's minimum width. Everything fits perfectly:

[image]

Here is what happens after the window has been resized horizontally:

[image]

As you can see (Viewing the highlighted post, which has a darker background color), the container shrinks, and the text is cut off. Here is my code:

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName("window")
        self.resize(850, 650)
        self.setWindowTitle("qt-devRant by AlgoRythm")

        header = QWidget(self)
        header.setObjectName("header")
        header.move(0, 0)
        self.header = header

        logo = QLabel(header)
        logo.move(10, 8)
        logo.setPixmap(logo_small.scaledToHeight(45, Qt.SmoothTransformation))

        name = QLabel(header)
        name.setObjectName("header-name")
        name.setText("devRant")
        name.setFont(comfortaa)
        name.move(60, 0)

        rant_scroller = QScrollArea(self)
        rant_scroller.setWidgetResizable(True)
        rant_scroller.setObjectName("rant-scroller")
        rant_scroller.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.rant_scroller = rant_scroller

        rant_area = QWidget()
        rant_area.setObjectName("rant-area")
        rant_scroller.setWidget(rant_area)
        self.rant_area = rant_area

        rant_scroller_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        rant_area.setLayout(rant_scroller_layout)
        rant_scroller_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        rant_scroller_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.rant_scroller_layout = rant_scroller_layout

        rants = Rant.get(limit=50)

        for rant in rants:
            test = RantContainer()
            test.rant_content.setText(rant.text)
            rant_scroller_layout.addWidget(test.container, 0, Qt.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignTop)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.do_sizing()

    def do_sizing(self):
        self.size_header()
        self.size_rant_scroller()

    def size_header(self):
        self.header.resize(self.width(), self.header.height())

    def size_rant_scroller(self):
        self.rant_scroller.move(0, self.header.height())
        self.rant_scroller.resize(self.width(), self.height() - self.header.height())
```

and in another file,

```
class RantContainer:

    def __init__(self):
        # Bad idea to subclass widget because it breaks painting
        # i.e. the background color goes bye bye
        # I'd love to. I really would. But just no.
        container = QWidget()
        container.setObjectName("rant-container")
        self.container = container

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        container.setLayout(layout)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        layout.setContentsMargins(60, 10, 10, 10)

        rant_content = QLabel()
        rant_content.setObjectName("rant-content")
        rant_content.setWordWrap(True)
        rant_content.setFont(rant_font)
        layout.addWidget(rant_content, 0, Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)
        self.rant_content = rant_content

        upvote_btn = QPushButton(container)
        upvote_btn.setObjectName("upvote-btn")
        upvote_btn.move(10, 10)
        upvote_btn.setFont(vote_button_font)
        upvote_btn.setText("++")
        self.upvote_btn = upvote_btn

        downvote_btn = QPushButton(container)
        downvote_btn.setObjectName("upvote-btn")
        downvote_btn.move(10, 80)
        downvote_btn.setFont(vote_button_font)
        downvote_btn.setText("--")
        self.downvote_btn = downvote_btn

        score_label = QLabel(container)
        score_label.setObjectName("rant-score")
        score_label.setText("69")
        score_label.setFont(score_font)
        score_label.move(12, 55)
        self.score_label = score_label
```

The QSS concerning these items:

```
QWidget#rant-container{
    background-color: white;
    min-height: 180px;
    min-width: 660px;
    max-width: 660px;
}
QWidget#rant-container:hover{
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by not using the layouts in `RantContainer`, It is also advisable to set the restrictions in the `rant-content` instead of `rant-container`.

```
class RantContainer:
    def __init__(self):
        # Bad idea to subclass widget because it breaks painting
        # i.e. the background color goes bye bye
        # I'd love to. I really would. But just no.
        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        container.setObjectName("rant-container")
        self.container = container

        rant_content = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        rant_content.setObjectName("rant-content")
        rant_content.setWordWrap(True)
        # rant_content.setFont(rant_font)
        self.rant_content = rant_content
        rant_content.setFixedWidth(600) # <---
        rant_content.setMinimumHeight(150) # <---

        upvote_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        upvote_btn.setObjectName("upvote-btn")
        # upvote_btn.setFont(vote_button_font)
        upvote_btn.setText("++")
        self.upvote_btn = upvote_btn

        downvote_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        downvote_btn.setObjectName("upvote-btn")
        # downvote_btn.setFont(vote_button_font)
        downvote_btn.setText("--")
        self.downvote_btn = downvote_btn

        score_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        score_label.setObjectName("rant-score")
        score_label.setText("69")
        # score_label.setFont(score_font)
        self.score_label = score_label

        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vlay.addWidget(upvote_btn)
        vlay.addWidget(score_label)
        vlay.addWidget(downvote_btn)
        vlay.addStretch()

        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(container)
        hlay.addLayout(vlay)
        hlay.addWidget(rant_content)
```

QSS:

```
QWidget#rant-container{
    background-color: white;
}
QWidget#rant-container:hover{
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

Or:

```
class RantContainer:
    def __init__(self):
        # Bad idea to subclass widget because it breaks painting
        # i.e. the background color goes bye bye
        # I'd love to. I really would. But just no.
        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        container.setObjectName("rant-container")
        self.container = container

        rant_content = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        rant_content.setObjectName("rant-content")
        rant_content.setWordWrap(True)
        # rant_content.setFont(rant_font)
        self.rant_content = rant_content

        upvote_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        upvote_btn.setObjectName("upvote-btn")
        # upvote_btn.setFont(vote_button_font)
        upvote_btn.setText("++")
        self.upvote_btn = upvote_btn

        downvote_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        downvote_btn.setObjectName("upvote-btn")
        # downvote_btn.setFont(vote_button_font)
        downvote_btn.setText("--")
        self.downvote_btn = downvote_btn

        score_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        score_label.setObjectName("rant-score")
        score_label.setText("69")
        # score_label.setFont(score_font)
        self.score_label = score_label

        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vlay.addWidget(upvote_btn)
        vlay.addWidget(score_label)
        vlay.addWidget(downvote_btn)
        vlay.addStretch()

        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(container)
        hlay.addLayout(vlay)
        hlay.addWidget(rant_content)
```

qss:

```
QWidget#rant-container{
    background-color: white;
}
QWidget#rant-container:hover{
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

QWidget#rant-content{
    min-height: 180px;
    min-width: 660px;
    max-width: 660px;
}
```

Comment: I still experience the issue with the provided code

Comment: @AlgoRythm I have added images that show that with my modification the problem is not observed, so probably the error is in another side so it would be advisable that you provide a [mcve], that is, a unique code that can easily be copied and executed, not just pieces of incomplete code., in the following link is my test code:  https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/90b0bb7471acf361460fb9d7bacdff25

Comment: I quickly copy and pasted your code into a new project and experience the same issues. Perhaps it is a Windows bug?

Comment: @AlgoRythm I copied your original code and observed the problem you were pointing out, with my code I solved it, in my case I use Linux, for what it could be. You could show a picture of what you get with my code

Comment: @AlgoRythm Have you used my test code: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/90b0bb7471acf361460fb9d7bacdff25 or have you just adapted my code to your initial code?

Comment: I have used your code verbaitm, and even installed the lorem package. I'll get that image to you, and switch to Linux and test my original code to see if it is just a Windows issue.

Comment: @AlgoRythm okay, great, what version of PyQt5 are you using?

Comment: 5.11.3 - here is the image showing text being clipped on resize: https://imgur.com/yirmwcn

Comment: @AlgoRythm I find it strange that the button has a wide width, in my case it takes the minimum

Comment: @AlgoRythm If you say that you have not modified anything in my code it seems to me that it is a bug, maybe the sizePolicy in windows and linux are different, for now I do not have a PC with windows at hand.

Comment: @elyllanesc I found that strange as well, but windows style must enforce a minimum width. I am on Ubuntu now, and the issue persists. It is seen as soon as the window is above the minimum width of 660px. Lorem seems to generate random text, so it is a bad choice to use as you will not notice missing text. Buttons are normal size on Ubuntu. It should be noted that sometimes text disappears a line at a time rather than clipping half a line, so it can be hard to notice.

Comment: @AlgoRythm lorem generates random text, but this remains fixed after establishing so it is not a bad option, on the other hand I only fixed the behavior of the first item since it should be indifferent. What version of PyQt5 are you using in Ubuntu?

Comment: @AlgoRythm in my case the text is not modified, that is, the number of rows does not change after a certain width, just increase the number of rows if I reduce the width as expected due to the wordWrap property. What I have written has a lot of logic, it seems strange to me what you get, in a few days I will try to test it on windows.

Comment: Same version. Do you mind stretching your window to be a bit larger? There's a small "safe zone" that I have observed, which your window may fall into. Also, should we move this to chat? I observe the issue at about 1600px width, on my machine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186749/discussion-between-eyllanesc-and-algorythm).